# RxJS Continuous HTTP polling in case it fails as well

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to implement HTTP-polling. The expectation is for every 5 minutes it should poll from HTTP or I could say sync on Server. In case if it fails, it shouldn't stop the subject but it should retry three times then again it should try after 5 mins. In case if it fails after 5 mins as well, it should retry 3 mins, and the scenario continuous to go on.

What I tried is something.

```
const checkTimeForRestart$ = Rx.Observable.timer(5 * 60 * 1000, 5000)
    .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.of(axios.get(url)).retry(3));

// .map(response => console.log(`console here !! - ${response}`));
// .concatMap(val => of(`Delayed by: ${val}ms`).pipe(delay(val)));

checkTimeForRestart$.subscribe(
    x => console.log(x),
    error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`),
    () => console.log(`Complete: fires when the observable completes`)
);
```

If the server is not up or for connectivity issues it shouldn't complete the observable, but should try for 3 times then again 5 mins after it would redo the process.

Comment: Did you try https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html ?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that when a it retries 3 times then the error notification is sent forward which disposes the chain and that's not what you want.

An easy solution is using `catch` (`catchError`in RxJS 6) to ignore the error after 3 retries:

```
const checkTimeForRestart$ = Rx.Observable.timer(5 * 60 * 1000, 5000)
  .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.of(axios.get(url))
    .retry(3)
    .catch(err => Rx.Observable.empty())
  );
```